# C structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to assign a structure to pointer by using another pointer

```
typedef struct cat Category;
Category{
///some stuff here
};


Category *categoryList;
Category *ap = &categoryList;
*ap = (Category *)malloc(sizeof(Category));
```

I get this:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'Category' from type 'struct Category *'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need to use ASCII solution way

Comment: First of all: Never cast the return value of malloc in c! ;)

Comment: by *ap you dereference the pointer...

Comment: type of (*ap) is struct Category.

Comment: It is clear that the OP is a newcomer to C. It is to be expected to have two or more errors in a single question... since when Stack Overflow became an experts only place to ask questions?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning pointer to pointer to structure Category to pointer to structure Category.. Yeah that's a lot of 'tos'. So how to fix it?

```
typedef struct cat Category;
Category{
///some stuff here
};

// declare variable - pointer to category
Category *categoryList;           
// store address of variable categoryList, which is pointer in variable ap,
// which needs to be of type Category ** since it is pointer to pointer!
Category **ap = &categoryList;     
// assign pointer to mallocated address to categoryList whose address is
// accessed - dereferenced via *ap
*ap = malloc(sizeof(Category));
```

Also please note, that you shouldn't cast return value of malloc. For explanation please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1474847)

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared with a pointer data type (ie, `Category*`) has a star counter, the number of [Asterisks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) on the data type.

That's it, the variable `x`:

```
typedef struct category_t { 
// ...
} Category;

Category* x;
```

`x` has a star counter = 1 because you have just one star.

Then remember this:

- Using the `&` operator increases the counter by one.
- Using the `*` operator reduces the counter by one.

Then, the expressions:

- `&x` has a star counter = 2, and
- `*x` has a star counter = 0.

You always need to match the datatype, including the star counter.

On your example you have two errors:

```
Category *categoryList;   // 1
Category *ap = &categoryList; // 2
*ap = (Category *)malloc(sizeof(Category)); // 3
```

On line 2 your variable `ap` has a star counter = 1, yet the expression `&categoryList` has a star counter = 2; this is an invalid assigment.

On line 3 your variable `ap` has again star counter = 1, yet the expression `*ap` has a star counter = 0 and you're assigning the result of `malloc` which has a star counter = 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    // Some stuff here
} Category;


int main() {

    // *categoryList doesn't initialize a struct, it only creates a pointer to one. Leave the * off.
    Category categoryList;
    // Assign the address of the categoryList struct to ap (a pointer)
    Category *ap = &categoryList; 
    ap = malloc(sizeof(Category)); // Try to never cast malloc.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking issues one at a time...

```
Category *categoryList;
```

The type of the variable `categoryList` is `Category *` ( pointer to `Category`).

```
Category *ap = &categoryList;
```

The type of the variable `ap` is `Category *`, but the type of the *expression* `&categoryList` is `Category **`, or "pointer to pointer to `Category`".  This is your first type mismatch; the assignment should be written

```
Category *ap = categoryList;
```

Finally,

```
*ap = (Category *)malloc(sizeof(Category));
```

The expression `*ap` has type `Category`; `malloc` returns a `void *`, which you are casting to `Category *`.  You cannot assign a pointer value to a non-pointer type, which is where your compiler error is coming from.  That line should be written

```
ap = malloc( sizeof *ap );
```

The cast is unnecessary<sup>1</sup>, and since the expression `*ap` has type `Category`, `sizeof *ap` will give the same result as `sizeof (Category)`<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1. The cast is necessary in C++ and in very old versions of C predating the 1989 standard.

2.  `sizeof` is an operator, not a function; the only time parentheses are required is when the operand is a type name.</sup>